# EJB 3.1 + design patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns, ejb-3.1, pojo

I have a a service layer composed of session beans. It is ok to let ejbs call pojos ? I want to use design patterns, for example strategy depending on a context, I call a certain strategy implemented as a pojo, is it mandatory to have the strategy classes EJBs too (may be performance, concurrecy...). What is the best practice ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is such a requirement, nor should there be.

Think of the converse: if you weren't using EJBs, would it be acceptable for those beans to call others that implemented the strategy pattern?  Of course it would be.

EJB is just one among many choices for deploying a distributed component.  I think there's value in implementing the functionality as a POJO, that may call other POJOs, and make the choice of remoting it as an EJB or web service or something else as late as possible.  If you decide that EJBs aren't for you, all you'd have to do is re-wrap your POJO as something else and off you go.  That POJO implementation will be reusable in non-EJB contexts that way.

Comment: Yes use of a façade implemented with session beans is an obligation in my context, wanted to know if the classes behind each session bean can be just pojos like that I can be free in using patterns. or may be due to concurrency, performance... I have to use only EJBs, applying patterns with classes that are EJBs could be fatal for performance I believe. What's the best practice ?

Comment: Where did you hear that bit about "fatal"?  And why the obsession with patterns?  The best practice is to write, test, and profile your code and fix what doesn't work.  EJBs from 1.0 have restrictions on starting threads, because thread management should be in the hands of the container, but you can get around that easily now using MDBs.